# How to seperate dates into specific time frames based on a given base date

Tags: python, python-datetime

I have a CSV file of various Sprint related metrics. One of those metrics is in a column named **Resolved** and it is the time at which a specific task was completed. This column contains strings which are formatted like this: **'May 27, 2020 3:38 AM'**.

I need to create a new column whose value is determined by looking at this string and deciding a specific time-frame to assign to it. The time-frames are based on Sprint dates.

In this case, a Sprint is always 2 weeks long and I know the starting date of one Sprint (8th July 2020).
Therefore to calculate sprint dates, we need to go 2 weeks ahead or back from 8th July 2020.
For example, the other sprint in July would then be 22nd July. Similarly, the ones in June would be 10th and 24th June and so on.

As an end to end example, if a row has the date 'May 18, 2020 4:58 PM', I need to calculate the correct Sprint starting date to assign to this row. The correct date in this case would be 13th May 2020. (Calculated by going back in 2 week time steps from 8th July until we get to May and then checking to see whether 18th May falls in the 13th May time bracket or 27th May).
However, if the date was 12th May instead, then the date would fall into the previous months last sprint, i.e. 29th April 2020.

As another example, if we got 'Aug 7, 2020 5:45 AM' then the correct date would be 5th August 2020.

I am converting the CSV strings to dates like this:

`new_date = datetime.strptime('May 27, 2020 3:38 AM', '%b %d, %Y %H:%M %p').date()`

I wrote up my own solution and it more or less does what I want:

```
#Base sprint date
base = '2020/07/08'
base_date = datetime.strptime(base, '%Y/%m/%d').date()
base_month = 7

#Converts the given string from the CSV
new_date = datetime.strptime(date, '%b %d, %Y %H:%M %p').date()
new_month = new_date.month

diff = new_month - base_month

if diff == 0:
    date_1 = base_date
    date_2 = base_date + relativedelta(weeks=+2)
    date_3 = base_date + relativedelta(weeks=-2)
            
    if new_date < date_2 and new_date >= date_1:
        return date_1

    elif new_date >= date_2:
        return date_2
    
    elif new_date < date_1:
        return date_3

elif diff < 0:
    diff = base_month - new_month

    base_num = 2*(diff + (diff-1))
            
    date_1 = base_date - relativedelta(weeks=+base_num)
    date_2 = base_date - relativedelta(weeks=+(base_num+2))
    date_3 = base_date - relativedelta(weeks=+(base_num+4))

    if new_date >= date_2 and new_date < date_1:
        return date_2
   
    elif new_date >= date_1:
        return date_1 
   
    elif new_date < date_2:
        return date_3 


elif diff > 0:
    base_num = 2*(diff + (diff-1))
            
    date_1 = base_date + relativedelta(weeks=+base_num)
    date_2 = base_date + relativedelta(weeks=+(base_num+2))
    date_3 = base_date + relativedelta(weeks=+(base_num+4))

    if new_date >= date_2 and new_date < date_3:
        return date_2
    
    elif new_date >= date_3:
        return date_3
    
    elif new_date < date_2:
        return date_1
```

But even though I don't have much programming experience it looks kind of awful and hacky and I wanted to look for better ways of doing this. Also, I don't need to worry about the year. It's kind of a one time thing and will only involve dates from 2020. Though if your solution caters to the years as well, I would definitley be interested in seeing it. Will be happy to provide more details and to clear up any ambiguities from my end.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like what you actually need is to use the modulo function on the timestamp, dividing by the number of seconds in two weeks. If you subtract that from the timestamp you get the relevant 2-week block starting date.

```
import time
from datetime import datetime, date

d = date(2015,1,5)
unixtime = time.mktime(d.timetuple())
twoweekseconds = 14*24*60*60

timepastmark = unixtime % twoweekseconds

twoweekboundary = unixtime - timepastmark
```

And don't forget relevant timezone conversions and offsets, I'm sure you can work those out yourself.